# There is a checkbox in vf page and onclick it should pass value to the apex property

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [edit] your question to add that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code

```
<apex:page controller="CheckboxValueC">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkboxShowP" value="{!isChecked}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!click}"/>
        </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex -

```
public class CheckboxValueC {

    public Boolean isChecked{ get; set; }
    
    public void click(){
        if(isChecked==true){
            System.debug('I am true');
        }
        else{
            System.debug('I am false');
        }
    }
}
```